# angular + Ionic 2 + ngrx/store - unsubscribe doesn't work

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, observable, ngrx-store

I have a ionic2 app with ngrx/store implemented and i'm encountering a strange behaviour.

```
nav:Subscription;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nav = this.store.select(fromRoot.getLoginState).subscribe(res => {
        if(res){
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }
    })
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.nav.unsubscribe()
}
```

store.select(fromRoot.getLoginState) returns a boolean and if it's true I want to set TabsPage as root in Ionic 2.
Obviously I only want it to happen once so I unsubscribe in the onDestroy lifecycle hook.

However the unsubscription doesn't seem to work and each time i get a state change it set the view back to Tabspage (so the subscription still fires)

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean by this `ngrx/store implemented`? can we have reference url about that?

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/store 
this.store.select(fromRoot.getLoginState) return an observable of a specific state, in this case is just a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be unsubscribing it inside the subscription as

```
this.nav = this.store.select(fromRoot.getLoginState).subscribe(res => {
        if(res){
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }
        //condition to check the required data is available 
         this.nav.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngrx` uses `rxjs` `Observable`s, which can easily be converted to `Promise`s for receiving single values like this when you don't care able being able to cancel the subscription before receiving a result.

If you truly only want a single value and won't be monitoring the store for login state updates, then `Observable.toPromise` is easier than messing with subscriptions, and makes the code's intent clearer IMHO.

Here's your example using `toPromise`:

```js
// notice no assignment here, since no need to unsubscribe
this.store.select(fromRoot.getLoginState).toPromise()
    .then(res => res && this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage));
```